# How can I install Github in windows 32bit Os?

Tags: visual-studio, github

How can I install GitHub on Windows 32 bit Operating System? As I didn't find a 32 bit GitHub version on the Internet.

Comment: [link1](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started-with-github-desktop/installing-github-desktop/)

Comment: did you find a suitable solution?

Comment: @NightTrain not yet...I think its not available for 32 bit.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use the official github client instead of GitKraken for example?

Answer (score 1):

The official GitHub app isn't the best anyway, so I would recommend to use another anyway!

I know about [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com). It's free but also not available for 32 bit.

There also is [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/download) which is only free for open source, edu, personal usage etc., but it's available for Windows 32 bit!

Answer (score 0):

From [issue 1214](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1214), there does not seem to be any support for a 32-bit version of GitHub Desktop.

Their own [tracking of usage](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1214#issuecomment-294834750) points to a vast majority of users with 64-bits Windows.